# Heating a premade tlayuda?

Tags: reheating, mexican-cuisine

I just picked up some ready-made, already-toasted [tlayuda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tlayuda) at a Latin American market. I'm wondering:

1. What is the standard/traditional method for heating these with toppings?
2. Is there a way to heat them on the grill?  They're big enough (like 40cm diameter) to be hard to fit into my oven.

Like I said, I've done some searching, but have found three kinds of recipes: those that have me making them from masa dough and serving immediately after toasting, those that have them served cold, and those that assume I'm substituting tortillas.  None are the case here; these tlayuda are pretty well toasted, so I'm wondering if I could spread them with black beans and heat them on a low grill.

I've had these at restaurants with melted cheese on top, and it's pretty common to buy them pre-toasted, so there must be a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely heat them on your grill. I would recommend a medium temperature, probably around 350° F. You want enough heat to thoroughly heat your toppings, but not so much that it kills the tlayuda while the toppings are getting hot.

I would also suggest placing a thin piece of foil under the tlayuda. I often do this when reheating a thin crust pizza as it allows the crust to get hot without overcooking it.

Comment: Thank you!  I wasn't sure I'd get an answer to this one.

Answer (score 2):

Reheat it like you should reheat a pizza, in the oven in a pan with the tempurture at 325F (162C)

Regarding it being too big that it might not/will not fit into your oven because 1t is 40cm in diameter, just cut it in pieces to fit (half, quarters, etc., whatever works)

Comment: I can't actually cut it into pieces; a toasted tlayuda is crispy, and would shatter rather than cutting.

Answer (score 0):

do not microwave it. the tortilla will become soggy. it's best to bring it to room temp while heating the oven. Have it cut in pieces where you buy it, say in half. 350° until heated through. it won't be as good as when it was made.

Comment: Hey Thomas!  I appreciate the thought, but I asked this question 3 years ago and it already has an answer.  Thanks for helping!